# the opposite of __add__?

Tags: python, python-3.x, operator-overloading

In python 3, I want to do operator overloading in a class I've made.

I know `__add__` stands for operator +.

What are the methods for `-`, `*`, `^`, `|` and `&`?

Comment: You can accept ThiefMaster's answer by clicking on the green checkmark near it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See [the python docs on the data model](http://docs.python.org/py3k/reference/datamodel.html#emulating-numeric-types).

The methods you asked about are: `__sub__`, `__mul__`, `__xor__`, `__or__` and `__and__`

Here's the full list:

```
object.__add__(self, other)
object.__sub__(self, other)
object.__mul__(self, other)
object.__truediv__(self, other)
object.__floordiv__(self, other)
object.__mod__(self, other)
object.__divmod__(self, other)
object.__pow__(self, other[, modulo])
object.__lshift__(self, other)
object.__rshift__(self, other)
object.__and__(self, other)
object.__xor__(self, other)
object.__or__(self, other)
```